Fine tuning a model for question-answering task without context on the dataset
I have a small dataset (contains around 2.5k question answer pairs) which I would like to train a T-5 base model on.
The code examples that I have came across fine-tune with a dataset which has question-answer-context, where the context has the answer and the model has to extract the answer from that context.
I'd like to fine-tune a LLM like T-5 on a question-answer dataset from a very narrow specific domain so that it can answer question from that domain.
How can I fine-tune T-5 base model just on question-answer data?
How can I ensure the fine-tuned model performs better than baseline?
Additionally, I have articles from my domain, how could i use them as well?
